# Redirecting the web client after deleting an item

Tags: php, comparative-review, url-routing, symfony2, crud

In my web-app, it is possible to delete an Item when visiting any of 4 different pages:

- the **Show Item** page
- the **Edit Item** page
- the **List Items** page
- the **List Items in Room** page

If the visitor uses a delete button on either of the 2 **List** pages, they should remain on their current page when the deletion is complete. But if the visitor is on the **Show** or **Edit** pages, they should be redirected to  the **List Items in Room** page when deletion is complete.

I have the following method in a Symfony3 controller, which uses the HTTP referer header:

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="ci_item_delete", requirements={"id"="\d+"}, options={"expose"=true})
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER') && is_granted('delete', item)")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Item $item
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Item $item)
{
    $referer = $request
        ->headers
        ->get('referer');
    $rpath = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_PATH );
    $badreferrers = array(
        $this->generateUrl('ci_item_show', ['id' => $item->getId()]),
        $this->generateUrl('ci_item_edit', ['id' => $item->getId()])
    );

    if(in_array($rpath, $badreferrers) ){ //coming from a page that won't exist once the Item is deleted
        $redirect = $this->generateUrl('ci_item_list_format_room', ['format_id'=> $item->getFormat()->getId(), 'room_id'=> $item->getRoom()->getId()]);
    } else {
        $redirect = $referer;
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($item);
    $em->flush();
    $this->addFlash('success', 'msg.delete.item.success');

    return $this->redirect($redirect);
}
```

Would it be better to have different routes for the different use cases? Something like this?

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="ci_item_delete", requirements={"id"="\d+"}, options={"expose"=true})
 * @Route("/deletefromlist/{id}", name="ci_item_delete_from_list", requirements={"id"="\d+"}, options={"expose"=true})
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER') && is_granted('delete', item)")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Item $item
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Item $item)
{
    $referer = $request
        ->headers
        ->get('referer');

    if($request->get('_route') == 'ci_item_delete' ){ //coming from a page that won't exist once the Item is deleted
        $redirect = $this->generateUrl('ci_item_list_format_room', ['format_id'=> $item->getFormat()->getId(), 'room_id'=> $item->getRoom()->getId()]);
    } else {
        $redirect = $referer;
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($item);
    $em->flush();
    $this->addFlash('success', 'msg.delete.item.success');

    return $this->redirect($redirect);
}
```

Or is there another better way altogether?

Comment: Please provide more context. Could you clarify the relationship between items and rooms?

Comment: @200_success, item is many-to-one with room with item on the owning side.

Answer (score 1):

There really is not much tangible difference between the two. I think I would not want to introduce a second route that does precisely the same thing as another route. I think it is sufficient to differentiate the redirect behavior based on the request properties.

In first, code example I think $badreferrers is a bad variable name. There is nothing bad about the referrer right? Those refererr values lead to a different redirect.